# Multiple Flat Rate Shipping Options

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, magento-community, shipping-methods

I need to add several different flat rate shipping methods to Magento. First, I need a way to offer flat rates for standard and express shipping methods (carrier independent). Secondly, I need to charge a flat handling fee per-item, with the option to charge an extra fee per each additional item.

For example, I want to charge a customer $1 for standard shipping on an order. Then I want to tack on a $10 handling fee for specific items, and $5 for each additional specific item - let's say the item is a jar of jellybeans.

If a customer orders a candy bar and two jars of jellybeans, I want to charge $1 for standard flat-rate shipping, plus $10 for the first jar and $5 for the other jar. So the total shipping and handling charge would be $16.

(Sorry, I know this may sound confusing.)

Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve this in Magento, or recommend an extension that will help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Matrixrate is the only extension I know which might do this. What you can do beside of this is to implement your own total model to handle this. http://blog.magestore.com/2012/09/07/magento-custom-total-models/

Answer (score 2):

have you looked into webshopapps matrixrate extension?

It is very versatile, and there is a free version. Paid for versions exist that has even more ability.

I use both paid and free on different sites, and been very happy with this module.